# Непрерывное движение при зажатой клавише

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

Не могу реализовать непрерывное движение при зажатой клавише. Зависает цикл и ничего не работает. Что не так?

<sup>Код должен выполнять следующее: есть круг, и его нужно двигать клавишами стрелок.</sup>

```
from graphics import *
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import pygame

FPS = 60
W = 700  # ширина экрана
H = 300  # высота экрана
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 70, 225)

pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# координаты и радиус круга
x = W // 2
y = H // 2
r = 50

while 1:
    sc.fill(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.circle(sc, BLUE, (x, y), r)

    pygame.display.update()

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_LEFT]:
        x -= 1

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_RIGHT]:
        x += 1

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_UP]:
        y -= 1

    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_DOWN]:
        y += 1
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: после `clock.tick(FPS)` добавьте `pygame.event.pump()`

Comment: Предлагаю, для лучшего понимания, пройтись ручками по книге Эрика Мэтиза "Программирование игр, визуализация данных, веб приложения". Прошу не кидаться тапками, потому-как слишком много объяснять, а разбираться в своих старых проекта... короче сложно. Но в этой книге довольно неплохо можно понять базовый код для PyGame и неплохо понять работу с классами.

Comment: @АлексейОсинный Хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: @godva Огромное спасибо! Добавьте это как ответ, чтобы я плюсанул и  принял.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

после `clock.tick(FPS)` добавьте `pygame.event.pump()`

Comment: Отлично, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Все же покопался в своих первых попытках и...
Вот мой вариант.

```
import pygame


def update_my_screen(event,mouse_x,mouse_y,my_simple_hero):
    if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:#Пример использованя мышки
        if event.button==1:
            print(mouse_x,mouse_y,'fire !!!')

    if event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:#Если кнопка клавиатуры нажата, то...
        if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:#Если это кнопка вправо, то...
            my_simple_hero.movie_right=True#перемещать героя вправо - Да!
        if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
            my_simple_hero.movie_left=True
        if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
            my_simple_hero.movie_forward=True
        if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
            my_simple_hero.movie_backward=True

    if event.type==pygame.KEYUP:#Если кнопка отжата, то...
        if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT:
            my_simple_hero.movie_right=False
        if event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
            my_simple_hero.movie_left=False
        if event.key==pygame.K_UP:
            my_simple_hero.movie_forward=False
        if event.key==pygame.K_DOWN:
            my_simple_hero.movie_backward=False
    #запуск функции нашего героя, которая меняет его расположение
    my_simple_hero.moving()

def draw_my_screen(my_simple_hero):
    my_simple_hero.draw_on_screen()#рисует уже обновновленного героя

def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1200,800))
    pygame.display.set_caption('My super-duper-mega Game!!!')
    clock=pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)
    game_active=True# Этот флаг нужен для завершения главного цикла игры
    mouse_x=0#если не добавить ошибка
    mouse_y=0#если не добавить ошибка
    my_simple_hero=MyCircle(screen)#Создание нашего персонажа, которого будем перемещать


    while game_active:#Главный цикл игры. Пока флаг - истина, игра работает
        screen.fill((255,255,255))

        for event in pygame.event.get():#получение всех событий
            if event.type==pygame.QUIT:#проверка события "Выход"
                game_active=False
            if event.type==pygame.MOUSEMOTION:#получение события движения мышкой
                mouse_x,mouse_y=event.pos#запись координат мышки в переменные

        update_my_screen(event,mouse_x,mouse_y,my_simple_hero)#Эта функция обновляет все переменные игры. Принимает в себя героя, чтобы изменять его параметры.

        draw_my_screen(my_simple_hero)#Эта функция рисует все объкты. Принимает в себя героя.

        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(30)
    pygame.quit()#Еслиб не добавить будет висеть окно

class MyCircle():#Класс нашего героя
    def __init__(self,screen,**kwargs):
        self.screen=screen#При инициализации получает ссылку на окно, в котором рисуются все на экране
        self.pos_x=100
        self.pos_y=100
        self.radius=10
        self.color=(0,0,255)
        #эти флажки нужны для постоянного перемещения героя
        self.movie_left=False
        self.movie_right=False
        self.movie_forward=False
        self.movie_backward=False

        #границы экрана за которые герой не перемещается
        self.max_y=800-self.radius
        self.max_x=1200-self.radius

    def moving(self):#перемещает героя
        if self.movie_left==True:
            self.pos_x-=5
            if self.pos_x<self.radius:
                self.pos_x=self.radius
        if self.movie_right==True:
            self.pos_x+=5
            if self.pos_x>self.max_x:
                self.pos_x=self.max_x
        if self.movie_forward==True:
            self.pos_y-=5
            if self.pos_y<self.radius:
                self.pos_y=self.radius
        if self.movie_backward==True:
            self.pos_y+=5
            if self.pos_y>self.max_y:
                self.pos_y=self.max_y

    def draw_on_screen(self):#рисует героя
        pygame.draw.circle(self.screen,self.color,(self.pos_x,self.pos_y),self.radius)

run_game()#запускаем нашу игру
```